# Gulp browserSync reload

Tags: javascript, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

So my question is, is there a way that when I run gulp watch through my terminal my browser doesn't load on a new page but instead reloads on the present page?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1qXi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for an option use the `gulp-livereload` library:

> npm install --save-dev gulp-livereload

`gulp-livereload` will not automatically listen for changes. You now have to manually call `livereload.listen` unless you set the option start:

> livereload({ start: true })

---

> `Usage`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
less = require('gulp-less'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  gulp.src('less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate the feedback.